# Handling large amounts of file uploads - Any limitations I should know of?

Tags: file-upload, file, filesystems

I'm building a website that will involve a lot of uploaded files. Hopefully, more than I intend for there to be.

I figured I'd have an uploaded files path and use a UUID as the filename. I was curious if there are any limitations on this? For instance, would storing thousands of files in the one folder on my server create problems?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite many issues that couldappear, from file system limitations to backup problems.

I suggest using the first X characters of tue UUIS as folder name - possibly multiple levels deep (first 4, second 43, third 4). This way you have one structure but can back up folders and move them to different servers if needed later (by using the folders as redirection points).